# What does OziExplorer mean by "RGB value"?

Tags: colors, rgb

The [OziExplorer File Formats documentation](http://www.rus-roads.ru/gps/help_ozi/fileformats.html) describes it's foreground and background colour fields as "RGB values". I have tried for about an hour to work out what it means by that. For example, here are some colours as exported by OziExplorer:

- Red: **5450740**
- Green: **65280**
- Blue: **16711680**
- Grey: **12632256**
- White: **16777215**
- "Transparent": **13158342**

I can't be 100% sure, but by the looks of it, the red, green and blue colours are **completely** red, green and blue, meaning **#FF0000** etc.

What I'm trying to do is understand what the above numbers mean. What is the link between the colour **(255, 0, 0)** and the number **5450740**? Where does the transparency come in? Can somebody help me clear this up?

---

I did notice a couple of interesting things. The hex value **#FF0000** has the decimal value **16711680**, which is the value Ozi Explorer output for blue. One would think **#FF0000** would mean red. Additionally, white (**16777215**) has the hex value **#FFFFFF**, which is at least "correct" according to the #RRGGBB standard.

---

**Edit:** After trying to create a waypoint file with the decimal values of **#FF0000**, **#00FF00** and **#0000FF** (red, green and blue) I found out that OziExplorer does indeed swap red and green. I still have no clue *why* it does that though, and I have no idea where the transparency fits in to this.

Comment: Off-the-wall hypothesis: The [wikipedia Talk page for the BMP file format article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ABMP_file_format) suggests that there's a "normal non-bitfield" variation on the format that stores the color bytes as GRB instead of RGB.  Could it be using this BMP variation internally?  At the bottom of the page there's alos a diagram of the bitfield format in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the colours are just normal 24-bit RGB values, but mirrored. Red is **#0000FF**, green is **#00FF00** as usual and blue is **#FF0000**. Also it turns out that there is no "alpha channel", just the colour value **#C6C7C8** which means "transparent".